# Can't name column in SQL Server after merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot save my results from the below (in the form of a view) as the second column has no name and I cannot add a "as" name to it or it no longer works.

The statement below is merging like rows and concatenating the different values where there are multiple results, regarding the bank details.

```
select [Pers#No#], 
        stuff(( Select distinct ', ' + 
                        cast( [Bank Account] as varchar(20) ) +  ' ' + 
                        cast( [Bank Keys] as varchar(20) )      
                FROM     [DATA].[dbo].[PA0009]                  as      S
                where   S.[Pers#No#] = T.[Pers#No#]
                For     XML PATH('')),1,1,''    )  
from    [DATA].[dbo].[PA0009]  
group by [Pers#No#]
```

Comment: Where are you putting the column alias (the `as`)?

Comment: First bracket before "stuff". Second bracket after "cast( [Bank Keys] as varchar(20) ) " and then this followed by " as [ColumnA]  "

Comment: Show current and desired outputs.

Comment: Please check answers below... I needed to move my " as [ColumnA] " to after the XML PATH part... THats the real end to the column....

Answer (score 3):

You should specify an alias to the column returning from the subquery:

```
select [Pers#No#], 
        stuff(( Select distinct ', ' + 
                        cast( [Bank Account] as varchar(20) ) +  ' ' + 
                        cast( [Bank Keys] as varchar(20) )      
                FROM     [DATA].[dbo].[PA0009]                  as      S
                where   S.[Pers#No#] = T.[Pers#No#]
                For     XML PATH('')),1,1,''    )  as whatever
from    [DATA].[dbo].[PA0009]  
group by [Pers#No#]
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find this a lot clearer and you also exccute the XMLPath *once* per `[Pers#No#]` value

```
select 
    p.[Pers#No#], 
    MyColumnName = STUFF(X.CSVValue, 1, 2, '')
from    
    (SELECT DISTINCT [Pers#No#] FROM [DATA].[dbo].[PA0009]) S
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    Select distinct 
        CSVValue = ', ' + cast( [Bank Account] as varchar(20) ) +  ' ' +  CAST( [Bank Keys] as varchar(20) )      
    FROM     [DATA].[dbo].[PA0009] T
    where   S.[Pers#No#] = T.[Pers#No#]
    For     XML PATH('')
    ) X
```

(Untested)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure? It worked for me:

```
CREATE TABLE PA0009 ([Pers#No#] INT , [Bank Account] VARCHAR(10), [Bank Keys] VARCHAR(10))

SELECT [Pers#No#]
    ,stuff((
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cast([Bank Account] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + cast([Bank Keys] AS VARCHAR(20))
            FROM  [PA0009] AS S
            WHERE S.[Pers#No#] = 132
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')  AS X 
FROM  [PA0009]
GROUP BY [Pers#No#]
```

Output:

```
Pers#No#    X
----------- ---------
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw I needed to move my "As" to after the XML PATH.....
So I was putting it too early and not naming it after the real end of the column... Thanks guys. I can maybe even delete this post if it doesn't seem valuable for others... I completely missed that.

```
 select [Pers#No#],  
  (
 stuff(( Select distinct ', ' + cast( [Bank Account] as varchar(20) ) +  ' '      + cast( [Bank Keys] as varchar(20) )      

                        FROM [DATA].[dbo].[PA0009]          as      S

                     where          S.[Pers#No#] = T.[Pers#No#]

                     For            XML PATH('')),1,1,''    )     ) as           [Concatenate_Details]     
 from [DATA].[dbo].[PA0009]       T
 group by [Pers#No#]
```